# Symfony2 flush() entities

Tags: php, symfony, flush, entities

I've a question about `$em->flush()` on Symfony2 Controller.

```
$v = $em->getRepository("ApplicationAdminBundle:VehiculeCompute")->findAll();
foreach ($v as $vehicule) {
    [...]
    $somme = {"compute before"};
    $veh = $em->getRepository("ApplicationAdminBundle:VehiculeCompute")->find($vehicule->getIdvehicules());
    $veh->setTaxeadditionnelle($somme);
    $em->flush();
    $total++;
}
```

So, to execute this loop, my script take very long time because I've got ~40,000 vehicules in my table.

I suppose `$em->flush()` in each loop isn't necessary...

```
$v = $em->getRepository("ApplicationAdminBundle:VehiculeCompute")->findAll();
$k = 0;
foreach ($v as $vehicule) {
    [...]
    $somme = {"compute before"};
    $veh[$k] = $em->getRepository("ApplicationAdminBundle:VehiculeCompute")->find($vehicule->getIdvehicules());
    $veh[$k]->setTaxeadditionnelle($somme);
    $total++;
}
$em->flush(); // Flush all of vehicule update ?!
unset($veh);
```

This version can work ?
Thank.

Comment: My initial thought is that this is an occasion where an ORM is inappropriate. You should probably use the Doctrine query builder to speak directly to the DBAL layer.

Comment: There some info about batch processing in the Doctrine docs - http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html#bulk-inserts

Comment: @Prisoner `persist` is for persisting new entities, when updating already persisted entity, it should not be used.

Comment: @RudySkate what does `setTaxeadditionnelle` do ? is it just a setter ?

Comment: @DinchoTodorov, you are indeed correct. I didn't correctly read the question.

Comment: @DinchoTodorov Yes, it's just a setter

Comment: Then @Fabien MEYNARD answer is much better solution, you don't need to query the DB and hydrate the object, then update and save them. Just issue UPDATE query

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the entity manager to perform the same operation on a large amount of data its recommended to process a query builder update like

```
$em
  ->getRepository('Foo')
  ->createQueryBuilder()
  ->update()
  ->field('bar')->set('value')
  ->getQuery()
  ->execute();
```

Else take care when using flush() on a large array. I had a few problems with this usage, solved by using array_chunk and flushing 100 or less items

Comment: Thx. I know this process with queryBuilder instance. I'll try with that ^^

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can flush every 20 at once as below. This works a lot faster.

```
$v = $em->getRepository("ApplicationAdminBundle:VehiculeCompute")->findAll();
$index = 0;
foreach ($v as $vehicule) {
    [...]
    $somme = {"compute before"};
    $veh = $em->getRepository("ApplicationAdminBundle:VehiculeCompute")->
                             find($vehicule->getIdvehicules());
    $veh->setTaxeadditionnelle($somme);
    $em->persist($veh);
    if($index%20==0)
        $em->flush();
    $index++;
}
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Without persit() because I just update `->find()` entity

Answer (score 0):

Thank everybody !
With a `$em->flush()` outside the loop and each entity in `$veh[]` array, ALL IS OK !